# Wazuh Kibana Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, kibana, wazuh

I have installed wazuh manager server, with elasticsearch and kibana. I can access to kibana web with no-login for now. And now I want to set it to access wazuh with AD access for whole company.

1. It is possible to do that on free version or do I need to buy elastic?
2. AD should be set on Wazuh login, or to Kibana web login, or to elasticsearch?? I know there can be login set for all three apps, but I am strugle to find out, which one is for AD.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for using Wazuh!

It is possible to integrate Active Directory with Elastic. You can find on how to configure it, [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/active-directory-realm.html). It is configured for Elasticsearch.

I hope this answers your question.
Cheers